# For Loop Iteration Inside of Javascript Variable (Django)

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a dropdown menu with selectors inside of django. I have made good progress in finding a piece of software that looks great!

http://nelrohd.github.io/bootstrap-dropdown-checkbox/

However, i am getting stuck on how to make it more dynamic.

The end goal is to have a filter option that consists of a list of applications that i can select and unselect in order to change what is outputted to the screen.

The way the software works is that it takes in a single variable through a jQuery selector:

```
    var myData = [{id: 1, label: "Test" }];
    $(".myDropdownCheckbox").dropdownCheckbox({
      data: myData,
      title: "Dropdown Checkbox"
    });
```

Right now i can only use hardcoded properties for the vars

```
    var data =[ 
        { id: "1", label: "Option 1", isChecked: true },
        { id: "2", label: "Option 2", isChecked: true },
        { id: "3", label: "Option 3", isChecked: true},
        { id: "4", label: "Option 4", isChecked: true },
        { id: "5", label: "Option 5", isChecked: true },
        { id: "6", label: "Option 6", isChecked: true},
        { id: "7", label: "Option 7", isChecked: true },
        { id: "8", label: "Option 8", isChecked: true },
        { id: "9", label: "Option 9", isChecked: true },
        { id: "10", label: "Option 10", isChecked: true },
    ];
```

I would like to find a way to make these properties iterable and able to pull a list from the django database: (something like:)

```
    var data=[
        for( var i = 0; i<=10, i++)
        {id: (i), label: (list(i)), isChecked: true},
    ]
```

I have tried to use django template tags, but cant seem to get that working either. My question is: is it possible to iterate over a for loop to create properties for a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
var data = [];

for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  data[data.length] = { id: (i + 1), label: 'Option ' + (i + 1), isChecked: true };
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks! That worked! Now ive just got to figure out how to pull in data from my django database to make it more dynamic... :)

Answer (score 0):

If you generate the list in Django, you can do like:

1. I will assume you have a list of arbitrary objects you want to serialize in Javascript. When you are ready to pass it to the response context, convert it with stuff like this: `mark_safe(json.dumps([{'id': element.id, 'label': element.label, 'isChecked': element.is_checked} for element in mylist]))`. This is just an example since I don't know which objects you want to render.
2. Assuming such safe and dumped json is sent to the `foo` context variable:

   ```
   var data = {{ foo }};
   ```

if you want to generate the options in pure javascript, there's nothing djangoish on it. A simple js for loop like @AlexandreThebaldi answer will work.

Answer (score 0):

I would double check to make sure you had the Django tags set up correctly. It should look like this by passing in the set of options as your context:

```
{% for opt in options %}
     {id: {{ forloop.counter }}, label: {{ opt }}, isChecked: true}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you! This has also helped, the problem was that i was referencing the wrong context! My context for this was objects... Here is the code that works!

        var data =[ ];

        {%for obj in objects %}
            {% for element in obj.display_application %}
                 data[data.length]={id: {{ forloop.counter }}, label: "{{ element }}", isChecked: true}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}